# Why is this ternary operator not working in this context?

Tags: php

Are there any issues with the following code (line 10 and 11 specifically with the ternary operators)? It doesn't seem to be working, and I can't figure out what is being done wrong.

```
$week_start = 1388991600; // Jan 5 2014
$week_end = 1401602400; // May 31 2014

// Show the first date's year if it is not in the same year as the end date
$same_years_week = ( $week_start % 31536000 === $week_end % 31536000 ? true : false );

// Show the second date's month if it is not in the same month as the end date
$same_months_week = ( $week_start % 2592000 === $week_end % 2592000 ? true : false );

$week_start_range = date('F j' . ( !$same_years_week ? ', Y' : '' ), $week_start);
$week_end_range = date(( !$same_months_week ? 'F ' : '' ) . ' j, Y', $week_end);

$week_range_label = $week_start_range .' &mdash; ' . $week_end_range;

print $week_range_label;
```

It seems that if on line 10 and 11 in my code, I do `!$same_years_week` or `!$same_months_week` then both always evaluate to true (no matter what the dates/years are set to) and if I remove the ! on either of them on those same lines it will always evaluate to false, again no matter what the give dates and their years/months are.

I have it set up in a sandbox here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2c61baf7e9d2377dabbdd653921dfba7826580a0

And I use http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm to generate my initial variables (to simulate the format I receive them in from a database on my site).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you compare years...

```
$week_start = 1388991600 % 3153600;  // 1407600
$week_end = 1401602400 % 3153600;    // 14018400
```

Those two values are different, so your IF() fails.

You want:

```
if (date('Y', $week_start) == date('Y', $week_end))
```

instead, so you're comparing **ACTUALL** year values, e.g. 2014 == 2014.

Comment: Marc, thanks, this is what I ended up using (for checking same months as well). Not sure why I didn't go this route in the first place, except that I had read to use my above method at some point in my online research. I believe that number (3153600) is seconds in a year, and I believed it would work for my code because time of day is not set for my dates.

Comment: yeah, if your timestamps were PURELY a date value, with h:m:s zeroed out, then it'd work... unless one of the dates represents a leap year, in which case it'd be broken again.

Comment: They were purely a date value, and none of the dates were in a leap year, and it still didn't work. Which is strange.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
$same_years_week  = ( ( $week_start % 31536000 ) === ( $week_end % 31536000 ) ? true : false );
$same_months_week = ( ( $week_start % 2592000  ) === ( $week_end % 2592000  ) ? true : false );
```

However you can skip this ternary and just do:

```
$same_years_week  = ( $week_start % 31536000 ) === ( $week_end % 31536000 );
$same_months_week = ( $week_start % 2592000  ) === ( $week_end % 2592000  );
```

Comment: see priority php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: hsz, thanks, this didn't seem to solve my main problem, but it does point out issues in my code.

Answer (score 0):

What hsz says, and `? true : false` doesn't make much sense and can be omitted:

```
$same_years_week  = ( ( $week_start % 31536000 ) === ( $week_end % 31536000 ) );
$same_months_week = ( ( $week_start % 2592000  ) === ( $week_end % 2592000  ) );
```

Also, be careful with unix times. If you're not in the UTC time zone, especially, if you're east of UTC, values calculated from "day X, 00:00:00" may wrap to the previous day, or even to a different week on weekends.